# Transluscent leaf using principled shader

Tags: cycles-render-engine, pbr

I this setup as shown in the screenshot. The image transparency plugs into the mix factor, the transparent and principled nodes plug into the mix shader inputs. I'm trying to figure out how to introduce translucency into the setup. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Leaf setup]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Final result:

[image: Final]

I will show you two methods, first one (**Translucent**) is recommended because it's a lot faster approach and also with less geometry. For both of them you will need **Mix Shader** with **Transparent BSDF** and **Alpha** from **Image Texture** as a **Factor**.

Example above is rendered with only 32 samples. Beneath both meshes there is a light source to show the effect.

### Translucent:

[image: Translucent]

Simple mix between **Principled BSDF** and **Translucent BSDF**, both with **Image Texture** as a **Color**. Factor between them will allow you to control how much light will go trough mesh.

### Subsurface:

For this method to work you will need to add some thickness to your mesh. I've added **Solidify Modifier** with pretty low value:

[image: solidify]

And node setup:

[image: subsurface]

Choose color of **Subsurface** to be close to the **Image Texture** and set **Subsurface strength**.

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks! And nice tip re mesh thickness and subsurface scattering as well, I didn't know that.

Comment: @cgslav, do you have a channel or website?

Comment: @RitaGeraghty check my profile here on BSE. Also yes, I do have YT channel but still thinking about the content ;)

Answer (score 2):

Why did you put Translucent shader in "Mix shader"? There should be "Add shader" and  you may change the value of transparency of the Translucent shader by increase/decrease brigthness of color of Translucent shader