# How can I just see the texture (and not the mesh) when I do my final render?

Tags: rendering

I make this and I unwrap it

[image]

then I put the texture on it but how can only the texture appear when I render it ? And not the shape of the mesh. (Like she appears in the object mode on the left of the screen) It's possible ?

[image]

Sorry I begin, thank you !

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93686/transluscent-leaf-using-principled-shader/93845#93845

Comment: Thank you ! Honestly I tried to make it but I still don't use the nodes. 
There is not a "easier" way for a beginner like me ?