# Where do i feed to Translucency map and AO map in the shader?

Tags: node-editor

[image]

First time playing with Blender making a leaf library from megascan textures.
Figured out where all the textures go except the translucency map and ambient occlusion map.

Could someone draw me a line showing where to connect them?

Cheers

Comment: Related: [How to properly hook up various maps types?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/174461/78972)

Comment: Also related: [Transluscent leaf using principled shader](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/93686/78972)

Answer (score 1):

You want to go with a node setup something like this - Use MixRGB to *multiply* the Ambient Occlusion value with your BaseColor, and use a Mix Shader to combine your Translucenct BSDF with your Principled BSDF.  See image below:

[image: Nodes]

Also, notice the areas I highlighted - these should be set to "non-color" color space. Additionally, to get the transparency to function correctly, you will have to change your Blend Modes to something other than "opaque" in your material properties settings.

Lastly, you can disregard the difference in names in my image textures, I just threw some in as examples to show the setup. Also, pardon my ugly node arrangement, I had to fit it all into one screen for a good sized screenshot.

Cheers.

Comment: thanks. Wow, this starts to get confusing. I will have a play.