# How to make the geometry transparent and shows the leaves only?

Tags: texturing

I want to create a bush.
There's a transparent image.
But how to make the black dissapear and left only the shape of the leaves image.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35127/how-to-make-transparent-material-in-cycles/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90392/how-do-i-get-transparency-to-work-with-the-principled-bsdf-shader https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93686/transluscent-leaf-using-principled-shader/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81851/does-transparency-work-in-eevee/129787#129787

Comment: Change the blend mode (right side) from _opaque_ to something else (alpha-blend works well for many things).

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect the alpha channel of the image node to the alpha input of the BSDF.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Eevee transparency]

With Eevee, you need to enable blend in the material settings:

[image: Material settings]

If you want the transparent parts to cast no shadows, you'll need to change the Shadow Mode to *Alpha Clip* or *Alpha Hashed*

Remember to connect the texture alpha in the alpha input of the shader node.